# Can small towns, who happen to be able to, choose to read on the 14th?

Tags: megillat-esther, tractate-megillah

This is a question on the first Mishnah in Masechet Megillah. The Mishnah says that since כפרים didn’t have readers, they would always travel to bigger cities to read the Megillah on Mondays or Thursdays (depending when the 14th was) and they would hear the Megillah being read by the Beis Din men there. So the Mishnah clearly states that all small towns must read the Megillah on Mondays or Thursdays (even if they don’t fall out on the 14th itself). My question is what if a small town did in fact have a Baal kore and the 14th fell on let’s say a Tuesday, would they be able to stay in their town and read from the Megillah on the 14th, or would they have to follow the Mishnah and read in a big city on Monday despite having a reader?

Answer (score 2):

The Gemara in [Megilla 4B](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.4b.4?lang=bi) concludes that the option to read the Megilla earlier is meant to make things easier for them, if they do choose, but not to require them to read it earlier;

> תָּא שְׁמַע, אָמַר רַבִּי יְהוּדָה: אֵימָתַי — בִּמְקוֹם שֶׁנִּכְנָסִים בַּשֵּׁנִי וּבַחֲמִישִׁי, אֲבָל מְקוֹם שֶׁאֵין נִכְנָסִים בַּשֵּׁנִי וּבַחֲמִישִׁי — אֵין קוֹרִין אוֹתָהּ אֶלָּא בִּזְמַנָּהּ. וְאִי סָלְקָא דַעְתָּךְ תַּקַּנְתָּא דִכְרַכִּין הִיא — מִשּׁוּם דְּאֵין נִכְנָסִים בַּשֵּׁנִי וּבַחֲמִישִׁי מַפְסְדִי לְהוּ לִכְרַכִּין?

> The Gemara continues: Come and hear that which was taught in the following mishna (5a): Rabbi Yehuda said: When is the Megilla read from the eleventh of Adar and onward? In a place where the villagers generally enter town on Monday and Thursday. However, in a place where they do not generally enter town on Monday and Thursday, one may read the Megilla only in its designated time, the fourteenth of Adar. The Gemara infers: If it enters your mind to say that the ordinance is for the benefit of the cities, would it be reasonable to suggest that because the villagers do not enter town on Monday and Thursday the residents of the cities should lose out and not be provided with food and water?

לָא תֵּימָא כְּדֵי שֶׁיְּסַפְּקוּ מַיִם וּמָזוֹן, אֶלָּא אֵימָא מִפְּנֵי  שֶׁמְּסַפְּקִים מַיִם וּמָזוֹן לַאֲחֵיהֶם שֶׁבַּכְּרַכִּין.

> The Gemara accepts this argument: Do not say that the Sages allowed the villages to advance their reading of the Megilla to the day of assembly so that they can be free to provide water and food to their brethren in the cities on the day of Purim. Rather, say that the Sages were lenient with them because the villages supply water and food to their brethren in the cities. This ordinance was established for the benefit of the villagers so that they should not have to make an extra trip to the cities to hear the reading of the Megilla. However, in a place where the villages do not go to the cities, advancing their reading of the Megilla to the day of assembly will not benefit them, and therefore they must read on the fourteenth

Comment: That's not exactly the conclusion. The conclusion is the goal is to make it easier for the townspeople. It doesn't say what would happen if they wanted to be "strict".

Comment: The premise of the question was based on the fact that the townspeople MUST read it earlier. That incorrect. They CAN read it earlier if they so choose but they don’t have to. If they choose not to then they would have to read it on the 14th and not any other day.

Comment: You don't have any proof to that. All you have proof to is that the rule about reading earlier doesn't apply when it wouldn't make things easier by allowing both trips to be combined into one. You don't know whether the rule allows them to choose to make things more difficult for themselves.